# Python Dictionary : Prevent previous value not overwritten by the new value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for ideas, pointers, to help me arrive at a solution, so as to prevent the previous values being over written. I have seen some list implementation, but wanted to see, if there is some better method out there

Scenario:
I want to read a Wireshark decoded file and put the information, into a Python Dictionary. I have written the code and have start putting the data into the Dictionary, starting with the DNS data, which I have included in the question.
The Code reads in the Data for the first DNS host and populates the Dictionary. Now when it comes to the second Host_Id, "1", it overwrites, the DNS Data value, including the Host_Id, field as well.

The snippet of the code is

```
dictionarynetworkobject = {}
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'] = 0
```

However,

```
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'] = 1
```

overwrites, data for HostId = 0. Same thing is happening for, TCP_Seq_ID and HTTP data.
I have looked a lot, however, did not find a better way to add, different values of "Host_Id", "TCP_Seq_ID" and "HTTP_Transaction_id", to the after the first value was written.

I have looked at the update, method, but it would not work. Also, I have tried

```
from collections import defaultdict
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
dictionarynetworkobject =  tree()
```

But this also does not work. I thought to pick group's Brain on this. Below is the Structure, I want to achieve.

```
networList = { 
            'DNS':  
                  {
                'Host_Id' : 
                           {
    { '0':  {'Local_Time':2015-10-02 17:20, 'DNS_Time': 2015-10-02 17:20,  'Num_Bytes':265, 'IP':1.2.3.4,'IPMODE':IPV4}}, 
    { '1':  {<-OverWriting the Previous Data->}}, 
    { '2':  {<-OverWriting the Previous Data->}},   
    { '3':  {<-OverWriting the Previous Data->}} 
                                    }
                    }                   

            'TCP': {    
                        'TCP_SEQ_NO':   {
                                        {'0': {TCP network data}}, 
                                        {'2': {TCP network data}}, 
                                        {'3': {TCP network data}},
                                        {'4': {TCP network data}}
                                        }   
                    },  

            'HTTP': {   'HTTP_Transaction_id': {
                                                    {'0': {HTTP data}}, 
                                                    {'1': {HTTP data}},
                                                    {'2': {HTTP data}},
                                                    {'3': {HTTP data}}
                                                }
                    }           
            }

________________________ Data for the DNS ____________________________________
Local_Time          Host_Id         DNS_Time     Num_Bytes      IP      IPMODE  
2015-10-02 17:20        0       2015-10-02 17:20    265         1.2.3.4  IPV4
2015-10-02 17:20        1       2015-10-02 17:20    106         5.6.7.8  IPV4
2015-10-02 17:20        2       2015-10-02 17:20    912         8.7.6.5  IPV4
2015-10-02 17:20        3       2015-10-02 17:20    913         4.3.2.1  IPV4
________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You want a collections.defaultdict, there are a million examples on SO if you have a search

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a structure like this, perhaps?

```
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'] = {}
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'][0] = {'Local_Time':2015-10-02 17:20, 'DNS_Time': 2015-10-02 17:20,  'Num_Bytes':265, 'IP':1.2.3.4,'IPMODE':'IPV4'}
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'][1] = {...}
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'][2] = {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but this: 
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'][1] = {...} keeps on overwriting the previous value. I am reading the values from the File in a sequence fashion, starting with 0, 1, 2, 3. So I am doing dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'][HostIdVariable] = {...}

Comment: Maybe you are having an issue with mutable vs immutable data structures.  Notice below:

a = {'key' : 1};   b = a ;  b['key'] = 100;  a == {'key': 100}


https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects

Answer (score 1):

You need `list` in `dict`

```
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'] = [] 
dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'].append(0)

dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'].append(1)

print(dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId'])
# [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as Python knows with your code you are just setting the location `dictionarynetworkobject['DNS']['HostId']` to the new value, what you need to do, as others have stated, is to make that value be a list and then append your new values to that list